# Date time in write.csv in R

Tags: r, date, csv, xts, posixct

I am having data frame named "data" with following column

```
>  2007-01-02 10:02:00
   2007-01-02 10:03:00
   2007-01-02 10:04:00
   2007-01-02 10:05:00
   2007-01-02 10:06:00
   2007-01-02 10:07:00
```

When I save data using write.csv(data,"Data.csv",row.names=F)  and csv open like

```
>  Column1            Column2
  2007-01-02    10:02:00
  2007-01-02    10:03:00
  2007-01-02    10:04:00
  2007-01-02    10:05:00
  2007-01-02    10:06:00
  2007-01-02    10:07:00
```

When I import the data in R again using read.csv("Data.csv"). It shows exact data format.

```
>  2007-01-02 10:02:00
   2007-01-02 10:03:00
   2007-01-02 10:04:00
   2007-01-02 10:05:00
   2007-01-02 10:06:00
   2007-01-02 10:07:00
```

I have no idea how come excel shows date and time in 2 separate columns while the datetime column in actually 1 column. How can I get the datetime in 1 column in csv format?

Answer (score 1):

How do you import the csv file into Excel? It usually offers a dialog box and you specify the separator, etc. My guess is you have the separator set to space, not comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try `write.table` instead and use `sep = ","`. I opened the resulting .csv file in LibreOffice Calc and it worked fine (well, despite the fact that LibreOffice reformats datetime column according to German conventions...).

Here's my code:

```
# Sample data
data <- as.data.frame(strptime(c("2007-01-02 10:02:00",
          "2007-01-02 10:03:00",
          "2007-01-02 10:04:00",
          "2007-01-02 10:05:00",
          "2007-01-02 10:06:00",
          "2007-01-02 10:07:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
names(data) <- "datetime"

# Write table
write.table(data, "Data.csv", sep = ",", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

# Read table
read.csv("Data.csv", header = FALSE)
```

Comment: `write.csv` gives the same results, so I don't think it is that.

Comment: Guess you're right. Your above suggestion dealing with data import in MS Excel seems quite reasonable!

Answer (score 0):

Your date should be stored as `as.character(as.Date())` before to export into excel